# iphone sdk: Core Audio How to continue recording to file after user stops recording by leaving the application and then re-opens it?

Tags: iphone, core-audio

The iPhone's AVAudioRecorder class will not allow you to open an existing file to continue a recording. Instead, it overwrites it. I'd like to know an approach that would allow me to continue recording to an existing file using Core Audio APIs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best bet would be to take a look at the [Audio Queue Services API](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  This is basically the next "deeper" level into the Core Audio stack provided by Apple.  Unfortunately, the chasm between AVAudioRecorder and Audio Queue Services is vast.  AQS is a C-based API and a fairly low level abstraction of the even more "raw" lowest levels of Core Audio.  I would suggest reviewing the guide above, then taking a look at the example [SpeakHere](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html).  It should easily be able to handle your current requirement.

No matter which API, you will have to handle the "intermediate" storage of your PCM data, probably temporarily storing it as a WAV or raw PCM, which you then reload and append with PCM data when continuing.